# Find a number a using strange computer

Tags: logic, computer-science

IN the $\#1$ slot of the computer memory there is number $a$. The computer is able to sum, multiply, divide and subtract from selected slots, writing the result in to the selected slot. It is also able to say about the number in the selected slot whether it is positive, negative or equals zero. The computer doesn't give any more information and it is not possible to write any numbers by yourself (it is possible to work only with number $a$ and its results with other numbers). How to find the number $a$ approximately, to a precision of $\frac{1}{1000000}$?

Comment: First: ask the computer whether $a$ is positive, negative or zero. If it is positive, continue subtracting $10^{-6}$ until the result is $\le 0$. If it is negative, do the same, but now add $10^{-6}$. If it is zero, well, $a=0$. That's all: with a single if and a single while loop you are done.

Comment: you are not able to enter any own numbers in computer slots ( subtracting your own number is impossible)

Comment: $a/a=1$. Then add $1$ to itself $10^6$ times. Then divide $1/10^6$. Is it legal?

Comment: suppose to be legal

Comment: @Crostul good idea,  though this goes off the assumption that you can specify a certain number of times to run an addition operation without actually storing the number,  I.e. not storing the number $10^6$ in a memory slot and yet using the number somehow